# What is the standard way to create an Angular Component in the browser?

Tags: javascript, angular, ecmascript-next, es6-modules

I am trying to create a simple JS/ESM based Angular example. It has been a while since I have been in the angular space and I see there are really 2 options

1. Using the UMD lib (I would like to avoid this)
2. Use the ESM2015 folder and load using ESM (this is what I would like to do)

I try doing this like...

```
<html>
    <head></head>
    <body ng-app="jrg-module">
        <jrg-element></jrg-element>
        <jrg-app></jrg-app>
        <script type="module">
            import { Component } from "//unpkg.com/@angular/core/esm2015/index.js";
            import { platformBrowserDynamic } from "//unpkg.com/@angular/platform-browser-dynamic/esm2015/index.js"
            import {ShadowElement, CREATE_ELEMENT} from "//unpkg.com/@jrg/ui/target/jrg-ui.esm.mjs";
            class JrgElement extends ShadowElement {
                constructor() {
                    super("<h1>CustomElement</h1>");
                    this.render();
                }
            }
            CREATE_ELEMENT("jrg-element", JrgElement, {});
            const MyComponent = Component({
                selector:"jrg-app",
                template:"<h1>Angular</h1>"
            }).Class({
                constructor: function() {}
            });
            const app = platformBrowserDynamic().bootstrapModule(MyComponent)
        </script>
    </body>
</html>
```

But (after taking forever to download 500+ files) I get

> Uncaught TypeError: Error resolving module specifier “rxjs”. Relative module specifiers must start with “./”, “../” or “/”.

Can I use the ESM version in the browser or do I have to use UMD? If I can use ESM from the browser is there a link to an example?

I swear Angular used to have a dropdown for their examples where you could switch between TS and JS but I don't see it now.

Answer (score -1):

Have you tried out the website [stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/) it has plenty of angular [examples](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ivy-9rexz7?file=src%2Findex.html) of setting up a new project.

You can also do `ng new my-app` from the [cli](https://cli.angular.io/) to generate a new project locally.

Angular has moved away from javascript in favor of typescript, so you will have to use ESM

Comment: I think you missed the "in the browser" part

Comment: Also this site does not support in browser Angular without TS. Also I understand they have gone another way but at the end of the day they publish ESM libs which do not require TS. I don't need TS and that isn't what I asked.

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference.  Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes. - [From Review](/review/low-quality-posts/27791001)

Comment: @Abhishek It is not for in the browser which is explicitly stated in the question MaxPowers the answer does not provide an answer for the situation I was careful to describe in the title

Comment: @Jackie I guess I don't know of an "in browser" solution for what you are looking for, everything I have ever seen for angular has been a project like I have shared. I guess I don't even know how you are getting angular core, compiler, rxjs, etc. without a package.json

Comment: @rhavelka fair enough, "In the browser" means instead of precompiling using npm and webpack or some such you just use the ESM module loader in the browser (See ESM). This means there is no Node or cli just the browser. This is typically handled using on of 2 module loaders ESM (Javascript native) or UMD (Older module loader that adds them to window). Because it uses no precompiler TS won't compile in the browser (there is a lib but OOS) so I need to use raw JS. 

I have done this in the past with the UMD lib but I would like to use the ESM ones.

Comment: The easiest thing to look at is https://angular.io/api/platform-browser-dynamic

Comment: This is what I know I need to use but as you can see no docs...

https://angular.io/api/platform-browser-dynamic/platformBrowserDynamic